Select2 multiple when I press button remove select item my modal is closed ,but my modal shouldn't close
This is my code tgoMeanItem id is multiple select2
<div class="col-lg-12 mt-2">
    <label for="date-field" class="form-label">
        <strong class="fw-bold">{{ strip_tags(__("translation.factory_number")) }}
            :</strong>
    </label>
    <select name="tgo_mean_item_id[]" multiple="multiple"
            class="form-control mo-form-input @error('tgo_mean_item_id') is-invalid @enderror"
            id="tgoMeanItem">
    </select>
    @error('tgo_mean_item_id')
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
        {{ strip_tags($message) }}
    </div>
    @enderror

</div>

when I press multi select defualt remove button , my modal automatic closed , it should not closed how I can do customize remove button in select 2 multiple

on click event try using event.preventDefault and event.stopPropagation

Please show the relevant code of the view and the class. Where is the modal? how/where is it triggered?

And what version of bootstrap because from bootstrap 5 and above modals has changed
